# Determine if XmlTextReader.Read() reads an end tag

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

`Using XmlTextReader.Read()`, how do I determine if what the reader read is an end/closing tag?

Note that I'm not looking for the usage of [XmlTextReader.IsEmptyElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.isemptyelement.aspx). I'm looking to verify whether given the following XML:

```
<thistag what="nothing">
   <inside color="cyan"/>
</thistag>
```

**Can I determine if the `thistag` tag I read is an opening tag or a end/closing tag?**

My solution so far involved checking for the presence of the `what` attribute:

```
if (reader.GetAttribute("what") == null)
{
    // it's an end tag!
}else{
    // it's a start tag!
}
```

But I understand that this approach isn't so elegant, and that it could fail if attributes aren't required for that specific tag.

Comment: FYI, you should not use `new XmlTextReader()` or `new XmlTextWriter()`. They have been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` or `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Comment: I'm interested in finding out why my question received a downvote. Please make a recommendation on how I can make it better or if there's anything wrong. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I notice you didn't include any code.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, I know you didn't. I was hoping that the person who downvoted would get my note. Anyway, do you think it's necessary to add code? I thought it wasn't necessary and the question was sufficient to make my point.

Comment: The code is necessary to show that you spent some effort; that you're not just here for us to "give you the codez"

Comment: @JohnSaunders Haha. I see your point. I'll edit to show what efforts I did so far before I received user3629979's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tried this, hope this helps:

```
XmlTextReader reader = null;

reader = new XmlTextReader(filename);
while (reader.Read()) 
{
  if(reader.NodeType==XmlNodeType.Element) // for opening tag
  {
    //your code

  }
  else if(reader.NodeType==XmlNodeType.EndElement) // for closing tag
  {
    //your code

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`XmlNodeType.Element` corresponds to opening nodes. `XmlNodeType.EndElement` is for closing nodes.